# My Firebase Cloud Function fails with Object.value is not a function error?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Why am I getting the following error when I try to fetch the values of my Firebase child nodes under registrationTokens:

**Database structure:**

```
"fcmtokens" : {
    "dBQdpR7l1WT2utKVxdX2" : {
      "registrationTokens" : {
        "O": ""c4PSCAUAg5s:Yw95DyVxwElE88LwX7" 
      }
    }
  }
```

**Console output:**

> TypeError: Object.values is not a function

**Part of my deployed function to Firebase Cloud Functions:**

```
return admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationTokens').once('value').then((userTok) => {

    const registrationTokens = Object.values(userTok.val());

    console.log('registrationTokens', registrationTokens
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object.values() is a feature new in ECMAScript 2017.

Cloud Functions runs node 6 by default, which only supports ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).  So, if you're running that code in the default Cloud Functions runtime, you will get that error (because the function doesn't exist).

node 8 supports ECMAScript 2017, and Cloud Functions allows you to deploy to node 8.  So, if you really need to use Object.values(), you should [deploy to node 8 instead](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version).  Or you can use the [lodash equivalent](https://lodash.com/docs/#values).

Comment: thanks Doug, I can stop pulling my hair out :) - this points me in the right direction now. thanks again.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please upvote and mark as correct.